# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.'

Tags: database

I am getting this exception while inserting data in Order Table.

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.'

Googled this exception to fix.

```
insert into dbo.order(orderStatus, plotTotalCost, totalPaidAmount,    
    installmentAmount, balanceAmount, depositAmount, depositReceiptNo, 
    depositDate, bankName, bankBranchName) 
values('Pending','650000','0','12500','600000','50000','15',
    '07/10/2019','HBL','Saddar')
```

Getting System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.'
Result: cannot insert data into the Order table.

Comment: notice it says "keyword".  Order is a keyword so it isn't a good name to use for your table. Try putting it in []:  dbo.[order]

Comment: Thanks, @Garr Godfrey